# display google map in cfwindow

Tags: html, coldfusion, google-maps-api-3, cfwindow

I would like to display a google map in a cfwindow. I created a cfwindow and set the source to the url which contains my google map. The html form beneath my map displays, but the actual map doesn't display. Why is this happening and what can I do to correct it?

see code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html> 
 <head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 

<script type="text/javascript"   
 src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
```

```
</head>
<body>
   <cfwindow name="w1" title="Location" initShow=true x=10 y=10 width="700" height="450" source="url to map">
    </cfwindow>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you post some code? It will make it easier for people to lend a hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the google map to render, it needs to fire off some javascript. When opening content in a cfwindow, embedded javascript won't always run.

Verify that your initialization javascript is running on the URL to the map, and if not, use `AjaxOnLoad` (CF8+) to ensure the initialization script runs. You also need to make sure that any script assets are included from the parent page.

This is absolutely possible (click Directions on [this example](http://www.landsofamerica.com/member/9455)).